# Is it possible to spawn 1-2 star wells after beating the game?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

The lowest star rating I've seen since beating the game is 3 stars, but there are some 1-2 star stuff that I don't have yet (such as Sinistea).  Is it possible to spawn those somehow?

Comment: Is it not possible to find a den that will spawn that Pokemon, but at a higher star level?

Comment: @Kadima no, sadly some of those unevolved pokemons only appear at 1-2 star levels.  I guess I can go catch them elsewhere but its just convenient if there's a few from a well I need without having to muck with weather and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible spawn 1 or 2 star raids after you finish the story. Raid dens will only spawn 3+ star raids.

I have confirmed this by playing 100+ hours after finishing the story, and never encountered a 1 or 2 star raid (except for those appearing in the Y-Comm). A few Youtubers doing raids have confirmed this as well.