# How to unlock 2 to 5 star max raid dens?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I am trying to do a speedrun through sword/shield but in the wild area I can only get 1 star raids no matter how long I try. I have looked online but can't find at which point 2 star dens and up become unlocked? The only thing I can figure is that it is based on the level catching limit set by the gyms, but I wonder then since a 2 star raid is supposed to be levels 25-30 will completing the first gym be enough since it only unlocks catching up tp level 25?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to spawn 1-2 star wells after beating the game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/361831/124566)

Comment: No I believe only 3 star and up are available then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least 2 badges in order to have 2 stars dens spawn.

| Star Value | Level Range | Badges Needed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ☆ | 15-20 | 0-1 |
| ☆☆ | 30-35 | 2-3 |
| ☆☆☆ | 40-45 | 3-4 |
| ☆☆☆☆ | 50-55 | 5-6 |
| ☆☆☆☆☆ | 60-65 | 7-8 |

Source, [Pokejungle](https://pokejungle.net/pokemon-sword-shield/pokemon-sword-shield-max-raids-tips-tricks/).